# How to safely navigate from button to a bottom navigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

so I have this button and it's the first entry point to the app. I want when users click it, it takes them to the home screen where we have bottom navigation items.

I keep getting a crash when I try to pass the direction from the button to just the Home Screen.

```
@Composable
fun OnboardingScreen(
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

       CustomeButton(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.explore_now),
                onClick = {  navController.navigate("bottom_navigation_screen") }
            )

}
```

I can't seem to get my navigation to work, it keeps crashing

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen( ) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigationBar(
                navController = navController,
                appItems = Destination.toList
            )
        },
        content = { padding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)) {
               AppBottomNavigation()
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun AppBottomNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = Destination.Favorite.route) {
      
        composable(Destination.Favorite.route) {
            FavoriteScreen()
        }
        composable(Destination.Info.route) {
            InfoScreen()
        }

        composable(Destination.Profile.route) {
            ProfileScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController, appItems: List<Destination>) {

    BottomNavigation(
        backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
        contentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.orange)
    ) {
        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
        appItems.forEach { item ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = { Icon(painterResource(id = item.icon), contentDescription = item.title) },
                label = { Text(text = item.title) },
                selectedContentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.orange),
                unselectedContentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.blue),
                alwaysShowLabel = false,
                selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(item.route) {
                        navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { route ->
                            popUpTo(route) {
                                saveState = true
                            }
                        }
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        restoreState = true
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the error message on logcat when your app is crashing?